# Joomla Login error: 500 when the username and password this incorrect

Tags: php, authentication, joomla

this error only appears when the website is online,
https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7656891_67295915_916242

But in the localhost this appears ok.
https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7656891_67295915_916482

how can i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Check your config file, and make sure that the server configuration is present instead of your local one.

Comment: i need to change this?
public $host = 'localhost'; to present? is it

Comment: Check this : http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_website_from_localhost_to_a_remote_host

Comment: i have made that and still the same error

Answer (score 3):

Just comment this line

```
$this->triggerEvent('onUserLoginFailure', array((array) $response));
```

libraries/joomla/application/application.php line 774

I had the same problem and I've tried many ways and I found that it is the easiest simple solution. Best luck.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened on my www.nairaforsms.com after I changed my CPanel username.

I solved it by editing the log and tmp paths in the configuration.php file. I replace the old username with the new username in the paths.

Answer (score 0):

In case of incorrect password,500 error message comes when we dont have enough permission.
Check your `tmp and logs folder`.And also `error.php` in logs folder must have write permission.

Comment: where do i change the permissions?

Comment: @Rick:In Joomla logs folder there is file error.php set write permission in this file.

Comment: @Rick Using `chmod` on the file through the Shel,l prompt you are offered by your hosting.

Comment: i have change that and sitl the same.
https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7656891_67295915_916242

Comment: @Rick:Check logs and temp path in configuration.php may be these paths are not correct.